# Protractor: Not able to extract value from an element and store it in a variable for future use

Tags: protractor

Here what is my testcase:
1) Get value of counters from elements of a page
2) Visit some other page so that the counter is increased on the original page
3) Again get counter values and compare with previous counter values

Here is  what I have done:

```
var x;
var ele = element(by.xpath("some value"));
        ele.getText().then(function(val){
            x = val;
        });
        expect(x).toEqual(0);
```

Output:
 Message:
     Expected undefined to equal 0.

I want to store the value in the global variable 'x' but protractor doesnt seems to store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the way store integer value for future use. Just needed to use ParseInt function of javascript.

```
         foo = function(ele){       
                return ele.getText().then(function(val){
                  return parseInt(val);
                });
            };
         ele = element(by.id(...));  
         val_ele = foo(ele);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    var ele = element(by.xpath("some value"));
    var x = ele.getText().then(function(val){
        return do_something_with_val(val);
    });
    expect(x).toEqual(0);
```

if you just want the text, then:

```
    var ele = element(by.xpath("some value"));
    expect(ele.getText()).toEqual(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I complicated the situation. It was a straight forward implementation as follows:

```
var ele = element(by.xpath("some value"));
var x = ele.getText();
expect(x).toEqual(0);
```